# Need a documentation for Video and Audio formats like AVI, WMV, WMA, MP3, MP4, WAV

Tags: audio, video, encoding, wmv

I need to make an video and audio encoder to convert raw video and audio samples to AVI, WMV formats. I am searching the internet but without success.

I am looking for a documentation of for at least AVI and WMV, WAV, WMA formats.
I need this to make or try to make an encoder for saving raw material from web cam using silverlight in a browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to reinvent the wheel? Writing video encoders is not a trivial task. And to be honest, if you couldn't even find any documentation for the WAV format using Google, writing an encoder for a handful of formats at once is probably too big a task...

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel but there is no open source, freeware or similar code to use in silverlight on client side. I don't know even if is possible to achieve this using Expression Encoder. I am waiting on the response for my previous question but nothing yet. If you know something please post me some links or title of any book. Thanks.